# Javascript exception popup even though code works fine

Tags: javascript, joomla, breezingforms

I have made a fee submission form and using Javascript to do calculation of amount paid and amount due and change status according to result. Here is my code:

```
function ff_Student_Form_init()
{
  setInterval("AdmissionCalc()", 500)
}

function AdmissionCalc(){

ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeeStatus').value='';
ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeeBalance').value=Number(ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFee').value)-Number(ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeePaid').value);

if(ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFee').value==0){
ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeeStatus').value="Not Applicable";
}
if(ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFee').value>0){
if ((ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFee').value == ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeeBalance').value)){

ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeeStatus').value="Unpaid";
}
}
if(ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFee').value>0){
if ((ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFee').value != ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeeBalance').value)){

ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeeStatus').value="Instalments";
}
}
if(ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFee').value>0){
if ((ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeeBalance').value == 0)){

ff_getElementByName('AdmissionFeeStatus').value="Paid";
}
}
 }
```

Unfortunately I am getting this exception popup but the script works fine can someone help.

```
*** EXCEPTION CAUGHT ***
PHP error level : E_NOTICE
PHP linenumber  : 7
Last known pos  : Before form custom piece code at line 1
Error message   : Undefined offset: 0

*** EXCEPTION CAUGHT ***
PHP error level : E_NOTICE
PHP linenumber  : 12
Last known pos  : Before form custom piece code at line 1
Error message   : Undefined offset: 0
```

Comment: Those are PHP errors, not Javascript.

Comment: this is what i don't understand too if i remove this jscript errors end too

Comment: What is on lines 7 and 12 of the PHP script?

Comment: another thing this form is made in Joomla Breezingform extension may be this is y the exception i m not a programmer i m just hitting in dark.

Comment: The form is built in Quickmode so it generate code on its own. I didn't programme it I just created this Jscript bit if i remove it the form works fine if i use it exception comes up.